# bad operand for binary operator - two types

Tags: java

I get this error; bad operand types for binary operator '-'. It happens on the line;

```
- p2.getProductNum();
```

If anyone could help with this exception It would be massively appreciated.

**the BetterBasket class**

```
package catalogue;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class BetterBasket extends Basket implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public boolean add( Product pr )
    { 
        super.add(pr);
        Collections.sort(this, new Comparator<Product>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
                    return p1.getProductNum() - p2.getProductNum();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Product class**

```
package catalogue;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Used to hold the following information about
 * a product: Product number, Description, Price and
 * Stock level.
 */

public class Product implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 20092506;
  private String theProductNum;       // Product number
  private String theDescription;      // Description of product
  private double thePrice;            // Price of product
  private int    theQuantity;         // Quantity involved

  /**
   * Construct a product details
   * @param aProductNum Product number
   * @param aDescription Description of product
   * @param aPrice The price of the product
   * @param aQuantity The Quantity of the product involved
   */
  public Product( String aProductNum, String aDescription,
                  double aPrice, int aQuantity )
  {
    theProductNum  = aProductNum;     // Product number
    theDescription = aDescription;    // Description of product
    thePrice       = aPrice;          // Price of product
    theQuantity    = aQuantity;       // Quantity involved
  }

  public String getProductNum()  { return theProductNum; }
  public String getDescription() { return theDescription; }
  public double getPrice()       { return thePrice; }
  public int    getQuantity()    { return theQuantity; }

  public void setProductNum( String aProductNum )
  { 
    theProductNum = aProductNum;
  }

  public void setDescription( String aDescription )
  { 
    theDescription = aDescription;
  }

  public void setPrice( double aPrice )
  { 
    thePrice = aPrice;
  }

  public void setQuantity( int aQuantity )
  { 
    theQuantity = aQuantity;
  }

}
```

**The Basket Class**

```
package catalogue;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * A collection of products from the CatShop.
 *  used to record the products that are to be/
 *   wished to be purchased.
 *
 */
public class Basket extends ArrayList<Product> implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
  private int    theOrderNum = 0;          // Order number

  /**
   * Constructor for a basket which is
   *  used to represent a customer order/ wish list
   */
  public Basket()
  {
    theOrderNum  = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Set the customers unique order number
   * Valid order Numbers 1 .. N
   * @param anOrderNum A unique order number
   */
  public void setOrderNum( int anOrderNum )
  {
    theOrderNum = anOrderNum;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the customers unique order number
   * @return the customers order number
   */
  public int getOrderNum()
  {
    return theOrderNum;
  }

  /**
   * Add a product to the Basket.
   * Product is appended to the end of the existing products
   * in the basket.
   * @param pr A product to be added to the basket
   * @return true if successfully adds the product
   */
  // Will be in the Java doc for Basket
  @Override
  public boolean add( Product pr )
  {                              
    return super.add( pr );     // Call add in ArrayList
  }

  /**
   * Returns a description of the products in the basket suitable for printing.
   * @return a string description of the basket products
   */
  public String getDetails()
  {
    Locale uk = Locale.UK;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    Formatter     fr = new Formatter(sb, uk);
    String csign = (Currency.getInstance( uk )).getSymbol();
    double total = 0.00;
    if ( theOrderNum != 0 )
      fr.format( "Order number: %03d\n", theOrderNum );

    if ( this.size() > 0 )
    {
      for ( Product pr: this )
      {
        int number = pr.getQuantity();
        fr.format("%-7s",       pr.getProductNum() );
        fr.format("%-14.14s ",  pr.getDescription() );
        fr.format("(%3d) ",     number );
        fr.format("%s%7.2f",    csign, pr.getPrice() * number );
        fr.format("\n");
        total += pr.getPrice() * number;
      }
      fr.format("----------------------------\n");
      fr.format("Total                       ");
      fr.format("%s%7.2f\n",    csign, total );
      fr.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include in your question the code for `getProductNum()` method from your `Product` class (use [Edit]).

Comment: @PM77-1 I have edited it in^

Comment: ``getProductNum()`` returns a String. What do you expect to happen when you subtract one String from another?

Comment: If the product numer is numerical, declare it (and the getter) as an ``int`` or ``long``, then the Comparator can be used as it is.

Comment: @f1sh could you edit that into my first part of the code. I'm completely confused

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
return p1.getProductNum() - p2.getProductNum();
```

with

```
p1.getProductNum().compareTo(p2.getProductNum());
```

both `p1.getProductNum()` and `p2.getProductNum()` are strings and you can't subtract them. 
 You want to compare them, because you need to create a `Comperator` to be used for sorting a `Collection` of `Product` objects.

Comment: I have added in the basket class above, however It now says cannot find symbol for the method - getProductNum(). What I am trying to do is merge repeated product items in the basket into one line. So if you order two watches, then instead of having two lines with quantity 1, the display will show a single line with quantity 2 (even if you ordered something else in between)

Comment: This is another issue. Edit your question or better post another question to explain the new problem.

Comment: @stallionstallion When I said *post another question to explain the new problem* I **did not mean** create a new account with a different username and repost the same question....

Answer (score 0):

`getProductNum()` returns a string.

If you'd like to keep this as a string for whatever reason, you'd want to use:

```
p1.getProductNum().compareTo(p2.getProductNum());
```

If you don't need a string then change:

`private String theProductNum;`

to:

```
`private int theProductNum;` and make sure the method returns an int :)
```